# Codeigniter 3: Undefined property: Controllername::$load

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working on a *Registration & Login* system in CI3.

My controller is is made according to the CI user guide:

```
class Signin extends CI_Controller {

 public function index()
 {
    $this->load->view('signin');
 }

 public function signin()
 {  
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
    if ($this->form_validation->run())
    {
        echo "You are in";
    }
    else
    {
        echo validation_errors();
    }
 }
}
```

I have loaded the libraries and helpers in *autoload.php*:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'form_validation', 'user_agent', 'session');

$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'form');
```

Yet I get this error:

```
Message: Undefined property: Signin::$load
Filename: controllers/Signin.php
```

Why is this? Thank you!

Comment: Have you add `constructor` in controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add a constructor in your `Signin` controller.

```
class Signin extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('signin');
    }

    public function signin()
    {  
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
        if ($this->form_validation->run())
        {
            echo "You are in";
        }
        else
        {
            echo validation_errors();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you need a constructor for your controller `Signin` in order to be able to use function `signin` (same name):

```
class Signin extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function signin()
   { 
      // your code
   }
   public function index()
   {
      $this->load->view('signin');
   }
}
```

see CI-manual about [reserved method names](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/controllers.html#reserved-method-names)

Comment: Why? What is the explication and how does that fit into my code?

Comment: parent::__construct(); is required as you are wanting access to everything within CI_Controller Class - without it then the only code this page is aware of is what is in it, therefore no `load` function etc.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have a class method with the same name as the class.

Per the documentation

> You should also never have a method named identically to its class name. If you do, and there is no __construct() method in the same class, then your e.g. Index::index() method will be executed as a class constructor! This is a PHP4 backwards-compatibility feature.

So the fix is to do one of the following

1. Change the definition of `public function signin()` to something else
2. Add a `__construct` method to the class.
3. Change the name of the class

I would use the first solution. Could be done as easily as

```
public function sign_in()
{
```